# Determine what is activated by QAction.activate(QAction.Trigger)

Tags: qgis, qt

I'm trying to build a plugin for Qgis where I want to use some functions of a default plugin. I would like to control the options that the user are supose to fill in while using the Interpolation plugin.

So far I have only managed to start the plugin in my python code with:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
for item in qgis.utils.plugins['processing'].iface.rasterMenu().actions():
    if "polation" in item.text():
        item.menu().actions()[0].activate(QAction.Trigger)
```

Now I want to fill in this form with python code: [image: Image of Interpolation plugin]

But I can't figure out what I activated with `item.menu().actions()[0].activate(QAction.Trigger)`, I've searched through the children of `item.menu().actions()[0]` but I can't find any with the title "Interpolation plugin" or anything else on the picture :(

I'd tried `item.menu().actions()[0].dumpObjectTree()` and got nothing in return..

Answer (score 2):

After weeks of trying and multiple tries with different solutions written in scipy, I finally found a working solution!

```
import processing
GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER = '%f,%f,%f,%f'% (min_lon, max_lon, min_lat , max_lat)
processing.runandload("grass:v.voronoi", path_and_file_name_point,False, False, GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER, -1, 0, 3, path_and_file_name_poly)
```

I had huge problems with getting the correct format for GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER. I had an extra space in the end which resulted in that no polygon file were created (I wrote `"= '%f, %f, %f, %f '%("` etc. instead of `"= '%f,%f,%f,%f'%(` " etc.)

The only "problem" that remains now are that it takes rather long time to run the process with 100k+ points.